# java.io.EOFException: Response had end of stream after 0 bytes

Tags: java, file-io, exception, httpurlconnection, webservice-client

I am trying to call a web service using a java code which is throwing **java.io.EOFException: Response had end of stream after 0 bytes** for the large chunk of data.

The same web service call works in Postman REST Client, but Java code throws an error and it is not able to fetch web service response.
Can someone please help me with this?

Below is the code snippet for reference:

```
        String output;          
        URL url = new URL(wsUrl);             //wsUrl is a web service URL

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        String authorization = "**************" + ":" + "*********";
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + java.util
                                          .Base64
                                          .getEncoder()
                                          .encodeToString(authorization.getBytes());
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        String jsonstring = new String();
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(output);
        }
        conn.disconnect();
```

Comment: I can only advise to use a standard Framework like Spring Web to handle all the connection stuff and concentrate more on the businbess logic then. Don't reinvent the wheel....

Comment: @Vinit: Can you share the `curl` request as generated by POSTMAN which succeeds in fetching response in your case ?

Comment: Throwing at which line?

Comment: @EJP -  line 'if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) '  throws an error.

Comment: @piy26 It is an enterprise application web service URL. Sorry I cant share the details.

Comment: @Vinit: If you have access to the server side code, can you verify if that code is sending the response code back ?

Comment: @VinitDeshkar: Regarding the curl request that I asked earlier, it was just to match the headers that POSTMAN sends and the one sent by your code. For the sake of confidentiality, just verify headers from the two on your own. POSTMAN does send a couple of headers by default and it could be that you need to send them explicitly via your application code.

Comment: @piy26 This is the cURL request -                                                   
 curl -X GET \
  ******************************************059872414/child/Data \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic b2FsLXNjcF93d0BvcdadDWyadawhdtOjVwRUhOLE5f' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: cb95961d-ec03-48e9-bb33-3cb55a8cf7ba'

Comment: @piy26 I dont have access to the server side code.

Comment: So the server closed the connection without sending anything, not even headers. Examine the server logs.

Comment: @VinitDeshkar I agree with @EJP. Also, not very important in this case but your cURL request doesn't have the `Accept` header.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck - it isn't needed.  Accessing the response code will trigger connecting and sending the request.